# JSON Text data reading in Java

Tags: java, json

I have text file with JSON data in it with following format:

```
[   {
    "belongs_to_suite": "no",
    "belongs_to_suite_id": "",
    "brand_family": "",
    "cat_manufacturer_id": 4382,
    "cat_sw_edition_id": null,
    "cat_sw_product_id": 38,
    "cat_sw_release_id": 47354894,    } ]
```

I want to read only `brand_family`, for which I suppose I need a JSON array.
Do I need to define this format using JSON objects first?

I have downloaded org.json lib, and I have following code in which I am reading the text file, but I cannot find out how do I define format and then import all data in `[{}...{}]` into an array and:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(br);
    String n = obj.getString("version");
    //int a = obj.getInt("age");
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Your JSON is an array, not an object. You can not read it into a `JSONObject`.

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't recognize the format and returns format error: ` JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray(br);
    
    for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
    {
     JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
     String version=obj.getString("version");
     System.out.println(version);
    } `

Comment: Plse [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29028703/edit) if you have code to share.

Comment: you've got an array of one element, so you may try to get your object with: `JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your JSON is an array, so firstly you should call:

`JSONArray array = new JSONArray(br);`

Then you can do something with the size or get the first object:

`JSONObject first = array.getJSONObject(0);`

And finally, having the `JSONObject`, you can extract and process any field:

`System.out.println(first.getString(""));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply as below :

```
      JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("D://jsontest.txt")));

                JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("obj");
                for(int i=0; i<lang.size(); i++){
                     JSONObject obj=(JSONObject) lang.get(i);
                     System.out.println(obj.get("brand_family"));
                  }

            }catch(Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Change your file to below :

```
{
  "obj": [
    {
        "belongs_to_suite": "no",
        "belongs_to_suite_id": "",
    "brand_family": "1",
        "cat_manufacturer_id": 4382,
        "cat_sw_edition_id": null,
        "cat_sw_product_id": 38,
        "cat_sw_release_id": 47354894
    },
    {
        "belongs_to_suite": "yes",
        "belongs_to_suite_id": "",
    "brand_family": "2",
        "cat_manufacturer_id": 4382,
        "cat_sw_edition_id": null,
        "cat_sw_product_id": 38,
        "cat_sw_release_id": 47354894
    }
  ]

}
```